# Repeating pseudo element issue in all versions of IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, pseudo-element, microsoft-edge

There seems to be an issue in IE 9, 10, 11 and Edge with pseudo elements where if they have a repeating background that is semi-transparent, the first half of the background-image is a lot darker than the rest of the image (almost as if there is overlap between the images). It's fine in all other browsers and seems to be such a unique thing that I couldn't find any references about it anywhere.

The effect that is trying to be achieved is to have an image shown, and a pattern with a certain opacity placed over the top to create a subtle pattern effect. Whilst there are other ways that this could potentially be achieved, this seems to be the easiest way.

[Image: Example of what is currently happening.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F08O2.png)

I made a quick CodePen example. If you look on any version of IE or Edge you'll notice that once the image has been displayed in full already, the second time it is repeated, the first half of the image is noticeably darker than the second half of the image as if that half has a higher opacity on it.

[CodePen: Example of the issue with code.](http://codepen.io/danieltj/pen/gwxLAO)

As you can see, the first image with a very basic pattern is fine. The second image though is quite large and has the same issue and I can't figure out what is causing it to do such a thing. Both images are repeating in the exact same way.

This is the code for the pseudo element, nothing out the ordinary in terms of CSS3 attributes or tricks etc.

```
.element::after {
    background-image: url(http://example.com/image.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    content: "";
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: can't reproduce the issue, same outcome in IE11 and FF49

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very strange bug. No idea why this happens. The problem is in the picture. If you reduce it to 1000px in width, for example, it will work well.

```css
body {
 background-color: #232323;
}

.wrap {
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 float: none;
 display: block;
}

.slider2 {
 width: 100%;
 height: 200px;
 margin: 10px 0;
 padding: 10px;
 float: left;
 display: block;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 position: relative;
}

.slider2::after {
 content: "";
 opacity: 1;

 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 display: block;

 background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/tmGMRCB.png');
 background-repeat: repeat;
 background-position: top left;
  
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap"> 
 <div class="slider2" style="background-image: url(http://img.wallpaperfolder.com/f/4A4B79479EAC/desert-sand-dunes-u6n12nvy10.jpg); background-position: top center;">
  Slider 2
 </div>
</div>
```

Solution: try to change picture.

Comment: You might need to increase the width of the images. In IE11 I get the following on JSFIddle. http://imgur.com/a/vxqdb *edit: like this on JSF; https://jsfiddle.net/0e8fpj3x/1/

Comment: Ok, understand you.

Comment: The problem is in image. I resized it to 1000px in width and it seems to work. You can run code snippet to check  it out.

Comment: This really is the strangest thing. So IE/Edge seems to have this issue when the image is an odd number. The original was 1027 pixels and I tried your image and it worked. I also got the original image and changed it to 1026 pixels and it works as well. Thanks for the help, this was such a headache!

Comment: Just found the exact same issue - seeing weird block colour on a semi-transparent background with ::after. It was 1285px wide, changed it to 1284px and we're all good!